# how to make a video preview with canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, video-thumbnails

this is my first question here!
im trying to make a website that show videos that i make and i want my viewers can see a preview of video when they hover mouse on the a  element or  element .
i just do it but i have some problems and questions. lemme show you code example first and then i ask my questions.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="thumbs"  style="width:216px;height:468px;border: 5px solid blue;background-color:red;"><canvas onmouseover="getid1(this);" onmouseout="getid2(this);" id="canvas1"></canvas></div>

        <script>
            var thumbsList = [];
            var delay = 100;
            var i = 0;
            var video = document.createElement("video");
            var a = 0;
            var m = document.getElementById("canvas1");
            var mtx = m.getContext("2d");
            var generate = true;
            var animstop = false;
            var vidFrames = 64;
        
            m.width = 216;
            m.height = 468;
            video.preload = "auto";
            video.src = "aaaa.mp4";
            
            function stranim(bb){
                    if(generate){
                        animstop = false;
                        video.currentTime = i;
                        generateVid();
                        generate = false;
                    }else{
                        animstop = false;
                        startAnim();
                    }
            }
            
            function stpanim(bb) {
                
                clearTimeout();
                animstop = true;
                mtx.drawImage(thumbsList[0], 0, 0); 
            }
            // if i replace this section with generateVid() the code is working
            /*video.addEventListener('seeked', function() {
                var d = (video.duration / vidFrames) * 2;
                generateThumbnail();
                i += video.duration / vidFrames;
                if (i <= video.duration) {
                    video.currentTime = i;
                    generateVid()
                    if(d == i){
                        startAnim();
                    }
                }
            });*/

            function generateVid() {
                var d = (video.duration / vidFrames) * 2;
                generateThumbnail();
                i += video.duration / vidFrames;
                if (i <= video.duration) {
                    video.currentTime = i;
                    generateVid();
                    if(d == i){
                        startAnim();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
                
            function generateFirstThumbnail() {
                var c = document.createElement("canvas");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                c.width = 216;
                c.height = 468;
                ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 216, 468);
                thumbsList.push(c); 
                thumbs.appendChild(m);
                mtx.drawImage(thumbsList[0], 0, 0); 
                i += video.duration / vidFrames;
            }
                
            function generateThumbnail() {
                var c = document.createElement("canvas");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                c.width = 216;
                c.height = 468;
                ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 216, 468);
                thumbsList.push(c); 
            }

            function startAnim() {
                var currentFrame = 0;
                function anim() {               
                    if(currentFrame != (vidFrames - 1) && animstop == false){
                        currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % thumbsList.length;
                        mtx.drawImage(thumbsList[currentFrame], 0, 0);                          
                        setTimeout(anim, delay); 
                    }
                }
                anim(); 
            }
            
            function getid1(obj) {
                stranim(obj.id)
            }
            
            function getid2(obj) {
                stpanim(obj.id)
            }
            window.onload = function(){
                
                generateFirstThumbnail();
            };
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the questions are :
1- why my generatevid() function is not working? this function is just like that eventlistener.
2- i want to add this code on a class to use it on multiple videos but idk how and i think this cant be done with js classes.( i search so many sites for it)
3-i can use 2d arrays for saving my video previews but is it dont make my site lower on load speed or it dont fill the ram of user?
4-there is any  way that i make this code better and easyer?(i dont want to use jquery for no reason).

Comment: this seems like if you dont use seek event the videoCurrent time will not change and it save frame 0 on all of array.i just added eventlistener on my function and its working rn but i feel bad about it and i think its not a good way to do it.but anyway its working rn

Answer (score 0):

For a pure js approach you can check this not mine btw: https://codepen.io/tepexic/pen/BazYgJe

html:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" id="input-tag"/>
<hr>
<video controls id="video-tag">
  <source id="video-source" src="splashVideo">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

JS

```
const videoSrc = document.querySelector("#video-source");
const videoTag = document.querySelector("#video-tag");
const inputTag = document.querySelector("#input-tag");

inputTag.addEventListener('change',  readVideo)

function readVideo(event) {
  console.log(event.target.files)
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log('loaded')
      videoSrc.src = e.target.result
      videoTag.load()
    }.bind(this)

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

But for other approach i would probably use http://ffmpeg.org/ library to generate a preview video (e.g 10 seconds video) and https://videojs.com library for video player so you have a control when user hover the player.

Comment: i dont want to make a video player.i just want to make a preview of my video as a canvas element and the why i want it to be canvas is i dont want my users download all video in main page.my code working if you use that section i commented but i dont want to use addeventlistener and the why is we cant use it in class.anyway thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I just did some test on your code, your video is getting seeked only once. No event is raised after that, which means your thumbnail will remain same.

Here is how I was able to fix it

```
    function generateVid() {
            var d = (video.duration / vidFrames) * 2;
             generateThumbnail();
            i += video.duration / vidFrames;
            
            if (i <= video.duration) {
               video.currentTime = i;
                console.log("starting seeking");
                
                if(d == i){
                    startAnim();
                }
                 
            }
            
        }
        
        video.onseeked = (event) => {
        if (animstop == false)
            {
            setTimeout(generateVid, delay); 
            }

        console.log("seeked");
        };
```

Comment: i have a seek event on my code where i commented but i dont want to use event listener.

Comment: @Ram if you don't want to use event listener then your script will start and run too fast. It will finish even before your first thumbnail has been rendered.